Label file in KITTI dataset
I am working on 3d object detection and came across PointPillars. PointPillars uses KITTI dataset.
Now I want to use my own dataset but first I should format my dataset like KITTI for that I want know what are those values in the label file of KITTI dataset. Can anyone explain me?

https://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/kitti/raw_data.php
